# Derivative of this scalar function (composed of matrices)

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I was wondering whether the following scalar function $y(z)$ can be differentiated wrt $z \in [0,1]$:

$$y(z) = \pi^\top (A + zB)^k e,$$ where $\pi, e \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are known parameters and $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is any natural number. If it helps, $A$ is invertible but $B$ is not.

Can this be done via the chain rule?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dz}=\lim_{\Delta z \to 0}\frac{1}{\Delta z}\left[\pi^T(A+(z+\Delta z)B)^ke-\pi^T(A+zB)^ke\right]$$
$$=\pi^T\lim_{\Delta z \to 0}\frac{(A+(z+\Delta z)B)^k-(A+zB)^k}{\Delta z}e$$
$$=\pi^T\lim_{\Delta z \to 0}\frac{(A+zB+\Delta z B)^k-(A+zB)^k}{\Delta z}e$$
$$=\pi^T\lim_{\Delta z \to 0}\frac{(A+zB)^k+(A+zB)^{k-1}\Delta z B+(A+zB)^{k-2}\Delta z B (A+zB)+\cdots-(A+zB)^k}{\Delta z}e$$
$$=\pi^T\left[(A+zB)^{k-1}B+(A+zB)^{k-2}B(A+zB)+(A+zB)^{k-3}B(A+zB)^2+\cdots+(A+zB)B(A+zB)^{k-2}+B(A+zB)^k\right]e$$

Comment: Thanks for the solution, much appreciated. Does this make the $j$th derivative of $y$ intractable?

Comment: @user202654 Yes I think so. Unless someone can come up with a cleverer answer than mine.